# Access to informations from my database in cakephp v2.9 (easy)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have an easy question , cuz i'm a beginner at cakephp.
so i have 2 tables(Ce,Produit) in my database, and i'm using the second table(Produit) in my first (Ce) by a foreign key. i mean the table "Ce" has the Id of Produit.
i'm trying to recieve information from my two tables in my view (détails) .
in my controller(detailsController) i used this :

```
$ce = $this->Ce->find('all', ['conditions' => ['Ce.id_lcc LIKE' => $id ] ]);
     $this->set(compact('ce'));
     $this->set('_serialize', ['ce']);
```

in my view (Details):

```
<?php foreach ($ce as $ce): ?>
              <?= h($ce->marque) ?>
```

and it's working, but i don't know how to call the second table (produit) ,i want something like this :

```
<?= h($ce->Produit->name_Produit ?>
```

i know this is not how it should be done, So if anyone can help me i'll appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Read the manual https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html there is a whole chapter about this.

Comment: but it didn't help me, it's too long and i have no time for reading all that, thank you anyway.

Comment: Honestly, find another profession if reading docs is not your cup of tea. It's an integral part of the profession as a developer.

Comment: Hint. you need to set your model associations as a class property, if your fields are named with correct conventions and you have used the right relationship type then cake will automatically grab data from the joined table https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types

Comment: thank you, that's what i did, it works now.